# Turning off cache in FME?

Tags: fme-form, cache

I did not find what I am looking for neither here nor in FME Website.
When I run some workflow I get that warning message (it is displayed in French I am not really sure of the accurate translation) :

> Cache functionality turn on. The workflow may run slowly because of saving features on each port and connexions

How may I turn off cache before running an heavy workflow ?

The fact is that sometimes FME stops because it has reached maximum memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn feature caching off from the Run menu > uncheck "Enable Feature Caching".
[image: Feature Caching]